# Metro UI not update

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, c#-5.0

I'm just start working on metro app and i'm facing a problem that is dispatcher not updating the UI. My code is below please let me know what was the issue ?

```
public class Test : DependencyObject
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentItemProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("NameOfPerson", typeof(string), typeof(Test), null);

    public String NameOfPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(CurrentItemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            runmethod(value);
        }
    }

    public async void runmethod(String text)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            SetValue(CurrentItemProperty, text);
        }
        );
    }
}
```

In main page i have an event button click which when fire update textbox.

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Test t = new Test();
        t.NameOfPerson = "Hello Umar";
    }
```

MainPage.xaml look like this

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApplication.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApplication"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
       <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,187,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="80" Width="255" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="textB" Text="{Binding NameOfPerson}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="80" Margin="730,187,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="307"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are what you are trying to do is having a button refresh your Text, you should look into the MVVM pattern and have the Binding update your UI.

To do this you'll have to create your Object, in this case, let's say a person.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Secondly you would want to have a person inside a viewmodel that you'll update using your button. The viewmodel will derive from BindableBase which is a part of Windows Store applications if you would use such thing as Basic Page. The Viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class MainPageViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public MainPageViewModel()
    {

    }

    private Person person;
    public Person Person
    {
        get { return person; }
        set { SetProperty(ref person, value); }
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        Person = new Person() { Name = "Simple name" };
    }

    public void UpdatePerson()
    {
        Person.Name = "Updated Name";
        OnPropertyChanged("Person");
    }
}
```

and in case you dont have the bindableBase, it looks like this:

```
    [Windows.Foundation.Metadata.WebHostHidden]
public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (object.Equals(storage, value)) return false;

        storage = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (eventHandler != null)
        {
            eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

On your MainPage you create the ViewModel and set the DataContext on your Page. Also you would want to handle your object inside your Viewmodel, so you'll create a update method when clicking the button that will modify your Person object:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly MainPageViewModel viewModel;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        viewModel = new MainPageViewModel();
        viewModel.LoadData();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;   
    }

    private void Button_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        viewModel.UpdatePerson();
    }
}
```

And finally your TextBox in the UI to point at the Person's name property inside the Viewmodel:

```
  <TextBox
        x:Name="textB"
        Text="{Binding Person.Name}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Height="80"
        Margin="730,187,0,0"
        TextWrapping="Wrap"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="307" />
```

I hope this fulfills your question on how you can have a button updating your UI.

Comment: Thanks. But the text box value still remain empty instead of showing hello umar.

Comment: If you do this, there is no point in making `runmethod()` `async` (or having `runmethod()` at all).

Comment: Still not working. Just consider my code that is shown. This is complete code of my application. Don't go in more details. Simple is that when button click my UI update. I need this functionality.

Comment: I'll suggest you'll use the MVVM pattern, see the modified answer above.

Comment: Is it necessary to use MVVM pattern. What if i not to use mvvm ??

Comment: When working with XAML the absolute best approach is to use MVVM, because bindings and MVVM works great together. I would definitely recommend it.